# Script to delete zip files

Tags: batch-file

```
7z a -tzip "C:\Test\Zipped\Zip" "C:\Test\*.*" -mx5 /MOV /MINAGE:1
```

Above command copies the files from Test folder, zips them and puts them in Zip folder.

```
forfiles /p C:\Test\Zipped\Zip /s /m *.zip* /d -10 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

It does not delete the files in Zip folder because its in zipped format. If it is a regular folder then it deletes the files.

Any thoughts?

Comment: At a file system level Zip-file is a file, not a folder, despite whatever Microsoft calls them, unless you use a transparent zip-mounter utility working at file-system level (that's a rare beast). Use `7z d archive.zip *.bak -r`, for example.

Comment: Could you please explain what would "7z d archive.zip *.bak -r" do?

Comment: I'm not sure what to explain... `d` command deletes specified files from the archive recursively. Read 7zip's documentation for more details.